# Maven assembly fileSet directory with wildcard

Tags: regex, maven

I'd like to know if it is possible (and how) to use wildcard in the **directory** tag of fileSet. Something like that:

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/../**/target</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>*-${project.version}-dist.zip</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

In alternative, if it is possible to use Regex.

Comment: No you can't do that. Can you explain exactly what is your use-case? What do you want to achieve? It looks like you're trying to assembly multiple distribution archives from different Maven projects (maybe modules?) into another big one? If this is the case, there are other approaches.

Comment: Exactly. I have sub-modules each with an assembly creating a zip archive. Finally I want to assembly all of these archive into another big one. To achieve that, I've created another submodule in order to do the trick. Isn't it the correct approach? What is the right one then?

Comment: In your specific module to create the big assembly, have a `<dependency>` on each of your other small assemblies. But to give a proper answer, could you edit your post with more info on your set-up? Example POMs, example wanted output, etc?